# SWTBot test outside Eclipse application

Tags: swtbot

I have an application that can run as a regular Eclipse plug-in, and I can test it with my SWTBot tests as usual.

The same plug-in application can be installed separately on my computer (like any other windows application).

The question is -  How can I configure the SWTBot tests to run on the separately installed application? (Instead of class name I need to use some folder/file name as the application place).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install SWTBot in your target application in one way or the other. Please see http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Automate_test_execution#On_an_already_packaged_RCP_application

Answer (score 0):

Tycho recently made it possible to run JUnit tests (so SWTBot ones too) against an existing application without much effort: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Testing_with_Surefire#p2Installed_on_provisioned_RCP_application