# Using SWTBot to automate a third party application. Is it possible?

Tags: java, automation, swtbot

I have a SWT application that I'd like to automate, making use of SWTBot. Is it possible? If yes, how?

All the examples I've found on the net seem to be more about testing your own applications than to launch a third party application.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but basically the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181246/swtbot-test-outside-eclipse-application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application in question is not an *Eclipse RCP* application to which you could install *SWTBot* I don't think it's doable. I don't think *SWTBot* can control another process even if it is Java process.

Only thing that comes to mind is some kind of [-Xbootclasspath:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) JAR that would *boot* some kind of "remote control server" in that application and allow *SWTBot* to issue commands to it.